# Sqlplus parameters and variables with default values

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

**Problem**

I have sql scripts which may use different tablespaces for different database users.

In order to remain flexible with the table creation I'd like to keep only 1 script and apply it to the various users. For that purpose I have something like this:

Tablespaces:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE MY_TABLESPACE DATAFILE 'MY_TABLESPACE.dat' SIZE 40M ONLINE; 
CREATE TABLESPACE MY_INDEXSPACE DATAFILE 'MY_INDEXSPACE.dat' SIZE 40M ONLINE;
```

And the table creation script:

```
define default_tablespace = 'MY_TABLESPACE';
define default_indexspace = 'MY_INDEXSPACE';

drop table test_table;

create table test_table ( id number )  tablespace &default_tablespace;
create index my_index on test_table( id) tablespace &default_indexspace;
```

i. e. I can't set a default tablespace for the user, because the index uses a different tablespace.

**Question**

Is it possible to override the definition of `default_tablespace` and `default_indexspace` depending on e. g. an environment variable?

Something like:

```
define default_tablespace = isEnviromentVariableSet( 'OTHER_TABLESPACE') ? getEnvironmentVariable( OTHER_TABLESPACE) : 'MY_TABLESPACE';
```

That way I could use different tablespaces whenever I invoke the script externally by some utility and at the same time I could keep the default tablespace.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Do you mean an operating system environment variable, or something set elsewhere in your session (e.g. a context)?

Comment: I prefer a session, but anything (session variable, system environment, execution parameter) will do if necessary. Whatever way is possible.

Comment: Your tables will be created in the default tablespace for the user(s) so can't you just prefix your scripts with create table schema.test_table etc.? or use set_current_schema?

Comment: Unfortunately not. "All I need" is a simple "if - else" depending on a variable being set or not.

Answer (score 0):

In DDL operation (create, drop, etc.) u can't use variables.

Easy way is use pl/sql anonymous block like this.

```
    declare
      my_tabable_space varchar2(100) default 'my_some_tablespace';
      other_tablespace varchar2(100);
    begin
      DBMS_SYSTEM.get_env('OTHER_TABLESPACE',other_tablespace);
      if other_tablespace is not null then
     my_tabable_space := other_tablespace ;
      end if;

      execute immediate 'create table test_table ( id number )  tablespace' || my_tabable_space;
    end;
/
```

and for select ENV variable u can use DBMS_SYSTEM.get_env ('NAME of VARIABLE', my_variable) but this package need DBA right (i think.. :-) )

Comment: Thanks, but I need an sqlplus solution, not a pl/sql solution. And most importantly the script should remain readable/maintainable as good as possible.